# Angularjs directive, two way binding does not bind

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, isolate-scope

All,

My understand of angularjs when it comes to directives is that when you have an isolate scope setup like so:

```
scope: {
  dataSource: '='
}
```

that inside the link function: `function(scope, ele, attr)`

the `scope` would have a `dataSource` property which is bound to `name` on my controller if used like this:

`<my-element data-source='name'></my-element>`

However this isn't the case, here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21879/

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the name of scope property `dataSource` to `source`. Because `data` is reserved name.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Batman';
})

.directive('myElement', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div>Hello {{source}}</div>',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
            source: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, ele, attr) {
            console.log(scope.source);
    }
  }

})
```

[Code Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21886/)

Comment: gah! thanks, those little gotcha's. I didn't know data was reserved. Is this a javascript or angular thing?

Comment: one more thing `rescrict: 'E' `, change to `restrict` :P